# OpenCV C++ - Windows IDEs

Tags: c++, opencv, ide

I'd like to start using OpenCV for C++ on Windows after a bunch of OpenCV4Android work.  From [this forum post](http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/Best-IDE-and-GUI-plugin-td2344558.html), it seems that not all C++ IDEs have equivalent capabilities to display OpenCV images, since some do not have an integrated GUI plugin.  Are there any differences between IDEs in terms of OpenCV functionality that I should be aware of?

Comment: I had to fight with code::blocks a bit, but that was not opencv's fault, I had the wrong listdc++.dll file.

Comment: Which of the many IDEs are you interested in?

Comment: Whichever offers the most general functionality ease of use, and also works fully with OpenCV.  So far, the only C++ IDE that I've worked with is Visual Studio.  It has amazing functionality but it's excessively complicated to set up the tiniest of applications, and I don't think it has the GUI capabilities to work with OpenCV.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go with **Qt Creator**. It's a cross-platform IDE for C/C++ development that supports the Qt framework. When you move to Linux/Mac you can continue to use [Qt Creator](http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qtcreator/2.7/2.7.0/qt-creator-windows-opensource-2.7.0.exe) to develop your projects.

It's an IDE that you'll spent a day or two to master, and it will be useful for the rest of your career.

Qt Creator uses a **.pro** file to configure the project. The instructions on this file are used to build all the *Makefiles* needed to build the **.exe**.

[This is the **.pro** file](https://raw.github.com/karlphillip/GraphicsProgramming/master/cvImage/cvImage.pro) I use to build my Qt Creator projects on Windows/Mac/Linux:

```
TEMPLATE = app    

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    cvImage.cpp

HEADERS += \
    cvImage.h

## OpenCV settings for Unix/Linux
unix:!mac {
    message("* Using settings for Unix/Linux.")
    INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv

    LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/ \
        -lopencv_core \
        -lopencv_highgui \
        -lopencv_imgproc
}

## OpenCV settings for Mac OS X
macx {
    message("* Using settings for Mac OS X.")
    INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv

    LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/ \
        -lopencv_core \
        -lopencv_highgui \
        -lopencv_imgproc
}

## OpenCV settings for Windows and OpenCV 2.4.2
win32 {
    message("* Using settings for Windows.")
    INCLUDEPATH += "C:\\opencv\\build\\include" \
                   "C:\\opencv\\build\\include\\opencv" \
                   "C:\\opencv\\build\\include\\opencv2"

    LIBS += -L"C:\\opencv\\build\\x86\\vc10\\lib" \
        -lopencv_core242 \
        -lopencv_highgui242 \
        -lopencv_imgproc242
}
```